# Add more values to same key using foreach

Tags: php, foreach

So I have array like this one:

```
[
    (int) 0 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20098238,
        'location_id' => (int) 20014727
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20098238,
        'location_id' => (int) 20027167
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20098238,
        'location_id' => (int) 20027168
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20098238,
        'location_id' => (int) 20027169
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20011189,
        'location_id' => (int) 20012490
    ],
    (int) 5 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20011189,
        'location_id' => (int) 20016161
    ],
    (int) 6 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20011189,
        'location_id' => (int) 20018679
    ],
    (int) 7 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20011189,
        'location_id' => (int) 20023569
    ],
    (int) 8 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20102015,
        'location_id' => (int) 20008315
    ],
    (int) 9 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20102015,
        'location_id' => (int) 20008689
    ],
    (int) 10 => [
        'user_id' => (int) 20102015,
        'location_id' => (int) 20021267
    ]
]
```

I want to get this as restult array like this one

```
[
    (int) 20098238 => [
        (int) 0 => (int) 20014727,
        (int) 1 => (int) 20027167,
        (int) 2 => (int) 20027168,
        (int) 3 => (int) 20027169

    ],
    (int) 20011189 => [
        (int) 0 => (int) 20012490,
        (int) 1 => (int) 20016161,
        (int) 2 => (int) 20018679,
        (int) 3 => (int) 20023569

    ],
    (int) 20102015 => [
        (int) 0 => (int) 20008315,
        (int) 1 => (int) 20008689,
        (int) 2 => (int) 20021267
    ]
]
```

Here is my code, but I am getting only part of sorting

```
$customerData = [];
foreach ($userIds as $data) {
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($customerData as $k => $check) {
    if ($k == $data['user_id']) {
      $customerData[$k][$i] = $data['location_id'];
    }
    $i++;
  }
  $customerData[$data['user_id']][$i] = $data['location_id'];
}
```

As result this code make key like user_id but there is problem with pushing array for that key. I am getting always maximal 2 locations per key.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: key `20102015` has 3 location_ids. Why there are only 2 locations for that key in your output?

Comment: Typing error. Each user_id should have all locations_ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Perfect Solution is here :

```
$customerData = [];
    foreach ($userIds as $data) {

      foreach ($customerData as $k => $check) {
        if ($k == $data['user_id'] && $data['location_id'] == $check) {
          $customerData[$k][] = $data['location_id'];
        }

      }
      $customerData[$data['user_id']][] = $data['location_id'];
    }
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/795177)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `$i` usage and use `$customerData[$k][]` in your loop. This will add a new occurance to the userid array automatically and as many as exist.

```
$customerData = [];

foreach ($userIds as $data) {

    foreach ($customerData as $k => $check) {
        $customerData[$k][] = $data['location_id'];
    }

}
```

Comment: in this soultion are duplicated data included

Comment: Sorry Duke. Is that a question or are you telling me it is duplicating something?

Comment: Opps sorry forgot to remove that last line. See answer amendment